# Node.js - TypeError: Client is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am trying the following:

```
  const { Client } = require('pg');

  console.log(Client);

  const client = new Client({
      user: 'Username censored',
      host: 'Host censored',
      database: 'gisuebung',
      password: 'Passworded censored',
      port: 5432,
  });
  
  client.connect();
```

When I run this however, I get the following Error: `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Client is not a constructor"`

I wrote this after a snippet I found online and it seems everywhere I look people did the exact same thing. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not enough informaiton. It can be a number of different things though, the likeliest would be a version issue i.e., pg dependency. Look into the version your using, as this seems to be a common issue version 2.0 ~

Comment: It worked well for me so try to check your dependencies or change your const name from `client` to something like `pgClient ` to check if is not an issue with the destructuring

Comment: worked for me too!

Comment: What does "*v-on handler*" refer to?

Comment: I am working with Vue.js, so v-on handler comes from there

Answer (score 8):

This is a JS error:

Try this, it worked for me:
`const { Client } = require('pg');`
`const Client = require('pg').Client;`

-- ES module:
`import pg from 'pg';`
`const Client = pg.Client;`

Comment: The missing piece here is the ESM part.

Comment: These aren't equivalent, the first sets Client twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fine for CommonJS.
But for ESM this error will raise.

Correct way to run in ESM:

```
import pg from 'pg'

const client = new pg.Client(config.dbConfig)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
 user: "postgres",
 database: "databasename",
 port: 5432,
 host: "localhost",
 password: "yourpassword",
 ssl: false
});


client.connect();
client.query("select * from cad_client")
     .then(results => {
         const result = results.rows
         console.log(result)
     })
     .finally(() => client.end())
```